# I want to know how to record and play radio waves?

Tags: remote-control

I want to make a universal remote.I have an ir receiver and transmiter. I.I can use it to control my tv and other equipment.I want to also control my dish network in the US. I checked and think that the dish uses 395mhz but i am not sure.**How can i replicate a dish remote radio signal**.I know it is radio signal and not ir. **What part do I need for the arduino?**

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, but should be enough to get you started.

The parts are:

1. Build a receiver http://www.somerset.net/arm/fm_only_lowtech.html
2. Tune it to the right frequency
3. Use it to detect the codes sent from your remote
4. Build a transmitter http://makezine.com/projects/super-simple-fm-transmitter/
5. Tune it to the right frequency
6. Transmit the codes
7. Success!

Step 3 is probably best done with a scope - you should find someone who has one, who can operate it, because they can be damaged.